# Vb.net grabbing time from sql server and formatting it wrong

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, datetime

I run this command in vb

```
select tuid, finish_time, bay 
from orders_table 
where tuid between 1001 and 1005 order by finish_time asc
```

which returns

```
tuid    finish_time                     bay
1005    2011-10-14 00:20:00.000          5
```

then I run this command in vb

```
While commander.Read()
   str = "update orders_table set start_time = (" & commander("finish_time") & ") where orders_table.tuid =" & num & ""
   Dim myCommand3 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(str, myConn2)
   myCommand3.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

When I do the debugger to see what str is sending to the database I get this

```
str "update orders_table set start_time = (10/14/2011 12:20:00 AM) where orders_table.tuid =1006"   String
```

It throws an error saying incorrect syntax near "12"

It formatting datetime and I don't want it to... how can i fix it so it looks like this

```
2011-10-14 00:20:00.000
```

Comment: Arg - it is **VERY BAD** to use string concatenation to build your sql this way. **DON'T DO IT!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `()` you can use `'` or `#` to delimit the DateTime:

```
str = "update orders_table set start_time = '" & commander("finish_time") & "' where orders_table.tuid =" & num & ""
```

This is **not** the recommended way of using SQL, however (string concatenation), as it opens your code up to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

It is **much** better to use parameterized queries, this will avoid the whole issue of escaping the values as well. See the answer @JoelCoehoorn gave.

Comment: @user please don't tell me you're not fixing the glaring security hole in your code :(

Comment: @oded - sorry for downvote, but I don't thing it's a good idea for future readers to see the string concatenation fix as a legitimate option.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - fair point. Wasn't thinking... Not that I can delete my answer, now that it's been accepted...

Answer (score 4):

Here is a **safe** and working version of your current code:

```
str = "UPDATE orders_table SET start_time = @start_time WHERE orders_table.tuid = @num"
Dim myCommand3 As New SqlCommand(str, myConn2)
myCommand3.Parameters.Add("@start_time", SqlDbType.DateTime)
myCommand3.Parameters.Add("@num", SqlDbType.Int)

While commander.Read()
    myCommand3.Parameters(0).Value = commander("finish_time")
    myCommand3.Parameters(1).Value = num
    myCommand3.ExecuteNonQuery()
End While
```

But an **even better** way is to re-write your sql so that it *all happens on the server*, and you never even read the your select results back to client code. You can write that all in one sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

you are formating the string with this (I assume this!)

```
commander("finish_time")
```

Just don't format it, or format it like in the database, but the difference lies in how you format it..